# Object Required Error , Array

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting the error 424 Object Required. I am very unfamiliar with arrays and assume it has something to do with that. I read a large number of the Object Required Error questions in this forum and tried the various suggestions, but none solved my issue.

At the top of the module

```
Dim velocityLookup As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim arrHolder As Variant
Const Velocity_Key_Col As Long = 10
Option Explicit
```

Custom SumIf for Arrays

```
Public Function SumIf(lookupTable As Variant, lookupColumn As Long, currentRow As Long, lookupValue As String, sumifColumn As Long) As Long
    Dim i As Long

    SumIf = 0

    For i = 1 To currentRow
        If lookupTable(i, lookupColumn) = lookupValue Then
            SumIf = SumIf + lookupTable(i, sumifColumn)
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Issue Line

```
        arrHolder(i, 18) = arrHolder(i, 24) - SumIf(arrHolder, 21, i, arrHolder(i, 21).Value, 26)
```

Entire Code

```
Sub Calculate_Click()

'******************* Insert a line to freeze screen here.
Dim wsMain As Worksheet
Dim wsQuantity As Worksheet
Dim wsVelocity As Worksheet
Dim wsParameters As Worksheet
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim lrMain As Long 'lr = last row
Dim lrQuantity As Long
Dim lrVelocity As Long
Dim lrParameters As Long
Dim lrData As Long
Dim i As Long 'Row Counter

'For Optimization Testing Only.
Dim MainTimer As Double
MainTimer = Timer

Set wsMain = Worksheets("Main Tab")
Set wsQuantity = Worksheets("Quantity Available")
Set wsVelocity = Worksheets("Velocity")
Set wsParameters = Worksheets("Parameters")
Set wsData = Worksheets("Data Input by Account")

lrMain = wsMain.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, Searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
lrQuantity = wsQuantity.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, Searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
lrVelocity = wsVelocity.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, Searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
lrParameters = wsParameters.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, Searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
lrData = wsData.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, Searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Dim calcWeek As Long
calcWeek = wsParameters.Range("B3").Value

For i = 2 To 5 'lrQuantity
    With wsQuantity
        .Cells(i, 5) = .Cells(i, 1) & .Cells(i, 2)
        .Cells(i, 6) = .Cells(i, 1) & UCase(.Cells(i, 2)) & .Cells(i, 3)
    End With
Next i

wsData.Range(wsData.Cells(2, 1), wsData.Cells(lrData, 4)).Sort _
key1:=wsData.Range("A2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

Dim tempLookup As Variant
For i = 2 To 5 'lrData
    tempLookup = Application.VLookup(wsData.Cells(i, 2), wsParameters.Range("Table5"), 2, False)
    If IsError(tempLookup) Then
        wsData.Cells(i, 3).Value = "Missing"
    Else
        wsData.Cells(i, 3).Value = tempLookup
    End If
Next i

For i = 2 To 5 'lrVelocity
    With wsVelocity
        .Cells(i, 10) = CStr(Trim(.Cells(i, 1) & .Cells(i, 4) & .Cells(i, 5) & .Cells(i, 9)))
        .Cells(i, 11) = .Cells(i, 6)
        .Cells(i, 12) = .Cells(i, 7)
        .Cells(i, 13) = .Cells(i, 8)
        .Cells(i, 14) = .Cells(i, 3)
        .Cells(i, 22) = .Cells(i, 1) & .Cells(i, 9)
    End With
Next i

wsVelocity.Range(wsVelocity.Cells(2, 1), wsVelocity.Cells(lrVelocity, 10)).Sort _
key1:=wsVelocity.Range("J2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

BuildVelocityLookup wsVelocity, Velocity_Key_Col, velocityLookup

Dim indexVelocity1 As Range
Dim indexVelocity2 As Range
Dim matchVelocity1 As Range
Dim matchVelocity2 As Range

With wsVelocity
    Set indexVelocity1 = .Range(.Cells(2, 7), .Cells(lrVelocity, 7))
    Set indexVelocity2 = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(lrVelocity, 3))
    Set matchVelocity1 = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lrVelocity, 1))
    Set matchVelocity2 = .Range(.Cells(2, 22), .Cells(lrVelocity, 22))
End With

Dim indexQuantity As Range
Dim matchQuantity As Range
With wsQuantity
    Set indexQuantity = .Range(.Cells(2, 4), .Cells(lrQuantity, 4))
    Set matchQuantity = .Range(.Cells(2, 6), .Cells(lrQuantity, 6))
End With

Dim ShipMin As Long
ShipMin = wsParameters.Cells(7, 2).Value

With wsMain
    .Range(.Cells(2, 9), .Cells(lrMain, 20)).ClearContents
    .Range(.Cells(2, 22), .Cells(lrMain, 47)).ClearContents
End With

arrHolder = wsMain.Range(wsMain.Cells(2, 1), wsMain.Cells(lrMain, 47))


For i = LBound(arrHolder) To lrMain

        Dim conUD As String 'con=concatenate
        'conUD = .Cells(i, 21) & .Cells(i, 4) & calcWeek
        conUD = arrHolder(i, 21) & arrHolder(i, 4) & calcWeek

        '.Cells(i, 21) = .Cells(i, 5) & .Cells(i, 3)
        arrHolder(i, 21) = arrHolder(i, 5) & arrHolder(i, 3)

        'If .Cells(i, 8) <> 0 Then
        '    .Cells(i, 9) = .Cells(i, 6) / .Cells(i, 8)
        'End If
        If arrHolder(i, 8) <> 0 Then
            arrHolder(i, 9) = arrHolder(i, 6) / arrHolder(i, 8)
        End If

        Dim velocityRow As Long
        If velocityLookup.Exists(conUD) Then
            velocityRow = velocityLookup.Item(conUD)
            tempLookup = wsVelocity.Cells(velocityRow, 11)

        '.Cells(i, 10).Value = tempLookup
        arrHolder(i, 10) = tempLookup

        tempLookup = wsVelocity.Cells(velocityRow, 14)

        '.Cells(i, 11).Value = tempLookup
        arrHolder(i, 11) = tempLookup


        'If .Cells(i, 9) > .Cells(i, 11) Then
        '    .Cells(i, 12).Value = Round((.Cells(i, 6) / .Cells(i, 11)) / .Cells(i, 10), 0.1)
        'End If
        If arrHolder(i, 9) > arrHolder(i, 11) Then
            arrHolder(i, 12) = Round((arrHolder(i, 6) / arrHolder(i, 11)) / arrHolder(i, 10), 0.1)
        End If

        'If .Cells(i, 6) > 0 Then
        '    If .Cells(i, 12) <> "" Then
        '        .Cells(i, 13).Value = .Cells(i, 12) - .Cells(i, 8)
        '    End If
        'End If
        If arrHolder(i, 6) > 0 Then
            If arrHolder(i, 12) <> vbNullString Then
                arrHolder(i, 13) = arrHolder(i, 12) - arrHolder(i, 8)
            End If
        End If

        Dim conECD As String

        'conECD = .Cells(i, 5) & .Cells(i, 3) & .Cells(i, 4) & calcWeek
        conECD = arrHolder(i, 5) & arrHolder(i, 3) & arrHolder(i, 4) & calcWeek

        ' It looks like you use this block a few times with different variables. Consider extracting to a function
        If velocityLookup.Exists(conECD) Then
            velocityRow = velocityLookup.Item(conECD)
            tempLookup = wsVelocity.Cells(velocityRow, 12)

        'If .Cells(i, 13) <> "" Then
        '    If tempLookup <> 0 Then
        '        .Cells(i, 14).Value = Int(.Cells(i, 13) / tempLookup)
        '    End If
        'End If
        If arrHolder(i, 13) <> vbNullString Then
            If tempLookup <> 0 Then
                arrHolder(i, 14) = Int(arrHolder(i, 13) / tempLookup)
            End If
        End If

            tempLookup = wsVelocity.Cells(velocityRow, 13)



        'If .Cells(i, 14) > tempLookup Then
        '    If .Cells(i, 14) <> "" Then
        '        .Cells(i, 15).Value = tempLookup
        '    End If
        'Else
        '    .Cells(i, 15).Value = .Cells(i, 14).Value
        'End If
        If arrHolder(i, 14) > tempLookup Then
            If arrHolder(i, 14) <> vbNullString Then
                arrHolder(i, 15) = tempLookup
            End If
        Else
            arrHolder(i, 15) = arrHolder(i, 14)
        End If

        'If .Cells(i, 14) = "" Then
        '    If .Cells(i, 11) = "" Then
        '        .Cells(i, 26) = ""
        '    Else
        '        .Cells(i, 26).Value = Round(.Cells(i, 14).Value * .Cells(i, 11).Value, 0)
        '    End If
        'End If
        If arrHolder(i, 14) = vbNullString Then
            If arrHolder(i, 11) = vbNullString Then
                arrHolder(i, 26) = vbNullString
            Else
                arrHolder(i, 26) = Round(arrHolder(i, 14) * arrHolder(i, 11), 0)
            End If
        End If


        'tempLookup = Application.Index(indexQuantity, Application.Match((.Cells(i, 21).Value & "LIBERTY") _
        '    , matchQuantity, False))
        Dim arrHolderRow As Long

        tempLookup = Application.Index(indexQuantity, Application.Match((arrHolder(i, 21) & "LIBERTY") _
            , matchQuantity, False))

        '.Cells(i, 24).Value = tempLookup
        arrHolder(i, 24) = tempLookup

        ' I havent used application SumIf on an array before, so I instead edited this so it should use the correct index value.
        ' This will likely not work as I want it to, so it may just need to go into a separate loop or something.
        ' .Cells(i, 18).Value = .Cells(i, 24) - Application.SumIf(.Range(.Cells(1, 21), .Cells(i, 21)), _
        '    .Cells(i, 21).Value, .Range(.Cells(1, 26), .Cells(i, 26)))
        arrHolder(i, 18) = arrHolder(i, 24) - SumIf(arrHolder, 21, i, arrHolder(i, 21).Value, 26)

        '  arrHolder(I, 18) = .Cells(I + 1, 24) - Application.SumIf(.Range(.Cells(1, 21), .Cells(I + 1, 21)), _
            .Cells(I + 1, 21).Value, .Range(.Cells(1, 26), .Cells(I + 1, 26)))
End If

            velocityRow = velocityLookup.Item(conUD)
            tempLookup = wsVelocity.Cells(velocityRow, 13)


        'If .Cells(i, 26) > tempLookup Then
        '    .Cells(i, 28).Value = tempLookup
        'Else
        '    .Cells(i, 28).Value = .Cells(i, 26).Value
        'End If
        If arrHolder(i, 26) > tempLookup Then
            arrHolder(i, 28) = tempLookup
        Else
            arrHolder(i, 28) = arrHolder(i, 26)
        End If

        'If .Cells(i, 18).Value < 0 Then
        '    .Cells(i, 29).Value = "C"
        '    .Cells(i, 27).Value = ""
        'Else
        '    .Cells(i, 27) = .Cells(i, 28)
        'End If
        If arrHolder(i, 18) < 0 Then
            arrHolder(i, 29) = "C"
            arrHolder(i, 27) = vbNullString
        Else
            arrHolder(i, 27) = arrHolder(i, 28)
        End If

        '.Cells(i, 31).Value = Application.SumIf(.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lrMain, 1)), _
        '    .Cells(i, 1).Value, .Range(.Cells(2, 27), .Cells(lrMain, 27)))
        ' Another SumIf. Same as before, we will have to figure this out separately.
        arrHolder(i, 31) = SumIf(arrHolder(), 1, i, arrHolder(i, 1).Value, 27)

        'arrHolder(I, 31) = Application.SumIf(.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lrMain, 1)), _
            .Cells(I + 1, 1).Value, .Range(.Cells(2, 27), .Cells(lrMain, 27)))

        'If .Cells(i, 5) = "" Then
        '    .Cells(i, 35) = ""
        'Else
        '    .Cells(i, 35).Value = Application.Index(indexVelocity1, _
        '    Application.Match(.Cells(i, 5), matchVelocity1, False))
        'End If
        ' Thinking about it now, I am not sure about Application Index/Match on an array either.
        If arrHolder(i, 5) = vbNullString Then
            arrHolder(i, 35) = vbNullString
        Else
            arrHolder(i, 35) = Application.Index(indexVelocity1, _
            Application.Match(arrHolder(i, 5), matchVelocity1, False))
        End If

        'If .Cells(i, 6).Value = 0 Then
        '    .Cells(i, 44).Value = 0
        'Else
        '    .Cells(i, 44).Value = Round(((((.Cells(i, 6).Value / .Cells(i, 11).Value) _
        '        / .Cells(i, 10).Value) - .Cells(i, 8).Value) / .Cells(i, 35).Value), 0.1)
        'End If
        If arrHolder(i, 6) = 0 Then
            arrHolder(i, 44) = 0
        Else
            arrHolder(i, 44) = Round(((((arrHolder(i, 6) / arrHolder(i, 11)) _
                / arrHolder(i, 10)) - arrHolder(i, 8)) / arrHolder(i, 35)), 0.1)
        End If

        'If .Cells(i, 6).Value = 0 Then
        '    .Cells(i, 34).Value = 0
        '    .Cells(i, 33) = 0
        'Else
        '    .Cells(i, 34).Value = Round(((((.Cells(i, 6) / .Cells(i, 11)) / _
        '    .Cells(i, 10)) - .Cells(i, 8)) / .Cells(i, 35)) * .Cells(i, 11), 0.1)
        '    If .Cells(i, 34) > 0 Then
        '        .Cells(i, 33) = .Cells(i, 34)
        '    Else
        '        .Cells(i, 33) = 0
        '    End If
        'End If
        If arrHolder(i, 6) = 0 Then
            arrHolder(i, 34) = 0
            arrHolder(i, 33) = 0
        Else
            arrHolder(i, 34) = Round(((((arrHolder(i, 6) / arrHolder(i, 11)) / _
            arrHolder(i, 10)) - arrHolder(i, 8)) / arrHolder(i, 35)) * arrHolder(i, 11), 0.1)
            If arrHolder(i, 34) > 0 Then
                arrHolder(i, 33) = arrHolder(i, 34)
            Else
                arrHolder(i, 33) = 0
            End If
        End If


        '.Cells(i, 37) = 1 + calcWeek
        arrHolder(i, 37) = 1 + calcWeek

        '.Cells(i, 38) = .Cells(i, 5) & .Cells(i, 37)
        arrHolder(i, 38) = arrHolder(i, 5) & arrHolder(i, 37)

        '.Cells(i, 39).Value = Application.Index(indexVelocity2, _
        '    Application.Match(.Cells(i, 38), matchVelocity2, False))
        arrHolder(i, 39) = Application.Index(indexVelocity2, _
            Application.Match(arrHolder(i, 38), matchVelocity2, False))

        '.Cells(i, 40) = Round(((((.Cells(i, 6) / .Cells(i, 11)) * .Cells(i, 39)) _
        '    - .Cells(i, 6)) - (.Cells(i, 8) - .Cells(i, 6))) / .Cells(i, 35), 0.1)
        arrHolder(i, 40) = Round(((((arrHolder(i, 6) / arrHolder(i, 11)) * arrHolder(i, 39)) _
            - arrHolder(i, 6)) - (arrHolder(i, 8) - arrHolder(i, 6))) / arrHolder(i, 35), 0.1)


        'If .Cells(i, 40) < 0 Then
        '    .Cells(i, 41) = 0
        'Else
        '    .Cells(i, 41) = .Cells(i, 40)
        'End If
        If arrHolder(i, 40) < 0 Then
            arrHolder(i, 41) = 0
        Else
           arrHolder(i, 41) = arrHolder(i, 40)
        End If

        '.Cells(i, 42) = .Cells(i, 41) - .Cells(i, 33)
        arrHolder(i, 42) = arrHolder(i, 41) - arrHolder(i, 33)

        'If .Cells(i, 11) < .Cells(1, 44) Then
        '    .Cells(i, 45) = 0
        '    .Cells(i, 32) = .Cells(i, 45)
        'Else
        '    .Cells(i, 32) = Application.Max(.Cells(i, 33), .Cells(i, 41))
        '    If .Cells(i, 44) < 0 Then
        '        .Cells(i, 45) = ""
        '    Else
        '        .Cells(i, 45) = .Cells(i, 44)
        '    End If
        'End If
        ' Not 100% sure if applicaiton.max will work here.
        If arrHolder(i, 11) < arrHolder(1, 44) Then
            arrHolder(i, 45) = 0
            arrHolder(i, 32) = arrHolder(i, 45)
        Else
            If arrHolder(i, 33) > arrHolder(i, 41) Then
                arrHolder(i, 32) = arrHolder(i, 33)
            Else
                arrHolder(i, 32) = arrHolder(i, 41)
            End If

            If arrHolder(i, 44) < 0 Then
                arrHolder(i, 45) = vbNullString
            Else
                arrHolder(i, 45) = arrHolder(i, 44)
            End If
        End If


        'If .Cells(i, 31) < ShipMin Then
        '    .Cells(i, 47) = 0
        'Else
        '    .Cells(i, 47) = .Cells(i, 27)
        'End If
        If arrHolder(i, 31) < ShipMin Then
            arrHolder(i, 47) = 0
        Else
            arrHolder(i, 47) = arrHolder(i, 27)
        End If

        '.Cells(i, 46) = .Cells(i, 1) & .Cells(i, 22) & .Cells(i, 47)
        arrHolder(i, 46) = arrHolder(i, 1) & arrHolder(i, 22) & arrHolder(i, 47)



    If (i Mod 100) = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Got to row "; i; " in "; Timer - MainTimer; " seconds."
    End If
End If
Next i

wsMain.Range(wsMain.Cells(2, 1), wsMain.Cells(lrMain, 47)).Value = arrHolder

Erase arrHolder

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the point of `.Value` in `arrHolder(i, 21).Value` ?

Comment: @JohnColeman Without it it throws a "ByRef argument type mimatch".

Comment: `SumIf(arrHolder, 21, i, CStr(arrHolder(i, 21)), 26)`?

Comment: @PatricK That worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Patrick Maybe you could post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

As per comments on your POST, your UDF indicates a String as an input which errors on `arrHolder(i, 18) = arrHolder(i, 24) - SumIf(arrHolder, 21, i, arrHolder(i, 21).Value, 26)`. You can just put convert to string `CStr()` around the Variant.

```
SumIf(arrHolder, 21, i, CStr(arrHolder(i, 21)), 26)
```